# Combine external modules with internal modules in TypeScript 0.9

Tags: module, typescript, external, internal

I want to build root namespaces into assemblies that are external modules. 
For example:

```
// File structure (every file is class or interface export)
Deferred/Deferred.ts
Deferred/Promise.ts
WebApp/ClassOne.ts
WebApp/ClassTwo.ts
```

I want assembly it to:

```
Deferred.js
WebApp.js
```

And both those files are AMD modules, so in Deferred.js (and WebApp.js) is something like:

```
define("Deferred", [], function() {
    (function(Deferred){
        // Here is a definition of a module with submodules
    })(var Deferred || (Deferred = {}));

    return Deferred;
});
```

How to do that?

Comment: Typescript cannot combine TS files using AMD or CommonJS modules.  You will have to do it yourself post build.

Comment: @RobertSlaney can you give a tip how to do that?

Comment: @FlyOn do that a basarat said. Use only external modules and after writing a code optimize it with r.js (this will drops unnecessary external requests).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file structure like:

```
// File structure (every file is class or interface export)
Deferred/Deferred.ts
Deferred/Promise.ts
Deferred/index.ts
WebApp/ClassOne.ts
WebApp/ClassTwo.ts
WebApp/index.ts
```

Where each index.ts imports and re-exports all the stuff from that folder. e.g. `Deferred/index.ts`:

```
import deferred_file = require('./Deferred');
export var deferred = deferred_file;
import promise_file = require('./Promise');
export var promise = promise_file;
```

Then compile this `index.ts` with `amd` flag and minify using r.js : http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html

PS: there is work being done in grunt-ts to create these `index.ts` files for you : https://github.com/grunt-ts/grunt-ts/pull/69 which you can work on if you want.

Comment: Is something similar possible for commonjs?

Comment: Yes https://github.com/grunt-ts/grunt-ts#transforms just compile with `--module commonjs` TypeScript does the correct codegen for you